# How can I remove a certain value in a flatmap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the `flatmap`:

```
 const options = names.flatMap(
    (object) => object.name + " - " + object.size + "- " + object.category
  );
```

`console.log(options)`:

[image]

If the `object.category` is equals to `S-XL` how can I not display its values? But if the `object.category`  is equals too `ft` it will display the `object.category` ?Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

I'll be using the `flatMap` here:

```
<Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.label === value?.label}
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={options}
        fullWidth
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Products" />}
        required
      />
```

Comment: I suppose you should `.flat()`, then `.filter()` and finally `.map()` to fomat it as strings... A sample of the data and a much clearer expected result would help.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'll be using it as the `options` in `Autocomplete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  const options = names.flatMap(
      (object) => 
               object.name + 
               " - " + 
              object.size + 
              `${object.category == "ft" ? "- " + object.category : ""}`
    );
```